# jQuery superfish menu / hover on iPad, iPhone etc

Tags: jquery, mobile, hover, superfish

I am using the [jQuery Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) plugin on a website I am working on. Works fine so far.

Problem is: I have to **optimize the site for mobile devices like iPad** etc.
After I click on a menu item the menu doesn't close itself as long as I click any other link on the page.

I have tried looking at the [Superfish code](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/js/superfish.js) and changing hover events to `click` events but without success.

I am not a pro when it comes to jQuery, so I would appreciate if anyone could help me out what I need to change to make this stuff work.

Comment: I had the same issue I just wrote the script with jquery without the superfish plugin. I don't even understand what is so special about super fish.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
//ipad and iphone fix
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    $("ul.sf-menu").bind('click',function() {
        $('ul.sf-menu').hideSuperfishUl();
    });
}
```

just add this to you document.ready
hope it will help..

Comment: I tried with this code. The menu was collapsed only when I tap on the image . It does not collapsed when I tap on the other place of the screen and dropdown arrow menu. Am I wrong something? Please help me.